# Call a function instead of throwing errors

Tags: python

I am trying to handle errors everywhere in the script. For example, if an error happens, it will call a function called `handle()`, which stops the program. Any ideas?

My code:

```
def handle():
    quit()


foo = "foo"
foo2 = 10
bar = foo + foo2
#Instead of throwing an error, call the handle function
```

Comment: One way is to wrap the code in `try - except` block and in `except` call the `handle()` method.

Comment: If you're coming from a language like BASIC where this kind of "global handler" is common, then the Python approach of local handling via `try .. except` may be a bit of culture shock, but it's worth getting accustomed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try and except:

```
foo = "foo"
foo2 = 10
try: 
   bar = foo + foo2 
except:
   handle()
```

If you need bar afterwards, just define it before the try catch block. For example, as `bar = 0`.

Also, if you want to know what the error actually was, you can do the following:

```
try: 
    bar = foo + foo2
except Exception as ex: 
    print(ex) 
    handle()
```

This isn't nearly as descriptive as the original exception, but it can give you a sense of what is going wrong without crashing your program.

Comment: If the goal is to print the exception and then swallow it, there's [a built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) for printing the same descriptive stack trace that Python gives by default.

Comment: Yes, you can do except: print(traceback.format_exc()) for that.

Comment: You might want to `except TypeError` rather than any `Exception` as that tends to hide problems you really want to see.

Comment: @JonSG: This code *isn't* hiding any problems with the `except Exception` because of it how it handles them — hiding them would be if all it did was `pass` whenever one happened.

Comment: @martineau unless it passes `ex` on, `handle()` knows nothing about the exception or why it happened. Here we see `handle()` trivially calls `quit()` but in practice we don't know for sure what `handle()` or `quit()` do. Has a beginner redefined `quit()`? I see beginners redefine `list` all the time so it seems more than plausible. Then any `Exception` even a `MemoryError` merrily goes on it's way being effectively ignored. In general, beginners should be strongly discouraged from trapping the base `Exception` IMHO.

Comment: @JonSG: Printing the exception is not ignoring it. Whether execution is allowed to continue is another matter.